# On Imagery: best practice opinions for folder arrangement?

Tags: discussion

Considering a long multi-project time horizon, What is most useful folder arrangement for you when it comes to imagery?

- *Sensor type > Date > Resolution > Project name* or
- *Date > Res > Sensor > ...* or
- *your > scheme > here*

Examples:

- `Landsat7/2015-07-18/`
- `2015/07/SPOT6/` etc.
- `orthos/2015/15cm/`
- `Region_name/satellite/infrared/30m`

Phrased another way: what arrangement would annoy you the least in case where your projects read imagery from a readonly source? (you can't alter the folder schema and it's not feasible to copy the files locally)

*(On meta because this is opinion based question)*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Meta GIS Stack Exchange is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of GIS Stack Exchange rather than discussing geographic information systems itself](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).  It should not be used as an alternative site for questions about GIS when they are not suitable for the Main site.

Comment: Best practice questions are highly relevant to people working in the field. I think in the long run we do ourselves a disservice by banning opinion directed questions. I don't have the time or energy to fight it though, so close as thou wilt.

Comment: [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing).

Comment: I'm aware of the sentiment in that thread. I don't agree with it. The prevailing opinion that equates finding out what the most common approach to situation X is as cargo cult thinking to be denigrated is mistaken. That's one of the central goals of one of the most highly repected and venerable knowledgebases on the internet, Ward Cuningham's original Wiki, finding design patterns so they can be repeated. (And btw, that post IS an opnion thread, and you offering it as supporting argument for the close decision here is the very embodiment "this is best practice". Deeply ironic and humourous.)

Comment: That post is a Meta discussion about how Stack Exchange sites work. This one seeks a discussion about a GIS topic. It is not about how GIS SE works so I think it is outside the scope of Meta GIS SE.

Comment: So if posted on main GIS SE you would not close it?

Comment: It seeks opinions which places it squarely under one of Main’s reasons to close. It’s fine for best practices to be sought and discussed in the GIS Chat Room but personally when I ask a focused question on Main I often find best practices amongst the answers.  It’s only asking for them in an open-ended question that I think is problematic.

Comment: This is a great question that comes up often especially with new users. Folder structure for analysis is essential for a good modern data science workflow and often so under utilized.  There are some new standards for storing remote sensing imagery that you may find address this issue https://github.com/radiantearth/stac-spec

Comment: excellent and relevant resource, thank you @GISHuman